# how to send email of current test in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am doing automation in Selenium Java. I have configured java mail API to send report. I have included it in `@Aftersuit` annotation. But here is the problem begins, it always send report of earlier executed tests. Is their any way to get current report.     I saw many solution but none seems working

Comment: What framework are you using? Where are your reports generated? What is the code you are using to send the report?

Comment: I am using POM, maven build. Reports are getting generated in trst-output folder. I am using java mail API to send report.